# Python: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'interp2d'

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spyder, netcdf

this code returns the error "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'interp2d'".  I'm attempting to learn how to interpolate values to fill an array given a few of the values in the array (sorry, bad phrasing).  Am I messing up the syntax for the interp2d function or what?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import scipy as sp

GCM_file = '/Users/Robert/Documents/Python Scripts/GCMfiles/ATM_echc0003_1979_2008.nc'
fh = Dataset(GCM_file, mode = 'r')

pressure = fh.variables['lev'][:]
lats = fh.variables['lat'][:]
temp = np.mean(fh.variables['t'][0,:,:,:,:], axis = (0, 3))
potential_temp = np.zeros((np.size(temp,axis=0), np.size(temp,axis=1)))

P0 = pressure[0] 
#plt.figure(0)
for j in range(0, 96):
    potential_temp[:,j] = temp[:, j] * (P0/ pressure[:]) ** .238


potential_temp_view = potential_temp.view()

temp_view = temp.view()

combo_t_and_pt = np.dstack((potential_temp_view,temp_view))
combo_view = combo_t_and_pt.view()

pt_and_t_flat=np.reshape(combo_view, (26*96,2))
t_flat = temp.flatten()
pt_flat = potential_temp.flatten()

temp_grid = np.zeros((2496,96))

for j in range(0, 2496):
    if j <= 95:
        temp_grid[j,j] = t_flat[j]
    else:
            temp_grid[j, j % 96] = t_flat[j]

'''Now you have the un-interpolated grid of all your values of t as a function of potential temp and latitude, so you have to interpolate the rest somehow....?'''

xlist = lats
ylist = pt_flat

X,Y = np.meshgrid(xlist,ylist)



temp_cubic = sp.interpolate.interp2d(xlist,ylist, temp_grid, kind = 'cubic')
#temp_linear= griddata(temp_grid, (X,Y), method = 'linear')
#temp_quintic = griddata(temp_grid, (X,Y), method = 'cubic')

plt.figure(0)
plt.contourf(X,Y, temp_cubic, 20)
```

EDIT: The error with this was pointed out to me. I changed the code from the interpolating line down into this, and I'm still getting an error, which reads "ValueError: Invalid input data".  Here's the traceback:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Robert/Documents/Python Scripts/attempt at defining potential temperature.py', wdir='C:/Users/Robert/Documents/Python Scripts')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-27-1ffd3fcc3aa1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Robert/Documents/Python Scripts/attempt at defining potential temperature.py', wdir='C:/Users/Robert/Documents/Python Scripts')
  File "C:\Users\Robert\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Robert\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 88, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Robert/Documents/Python Scripts/attempt at defining potential temperature.py", line 62, in <module>
    Z = temp_cubic(xlist,ylist)
  File "C:\Users\Robert\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 292, in __call__
    z = fitpack.bisplev(x, y, self.tck, dx, dy)
  File "C:\Users\Robert\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\fitpack.py", line 1048, in bisplev
    raise ValueError("Invalid input data")":

temp_cubic = sp.interpolate.interp2d(xlist, ylist, temp_grid, kind = 'cubic')

ylist = np.linspace(np.min(pt_flat), np.max(pt_flat), .01)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(xlist,ylist)
Z = temp_cubic(xlist,ylist)
plt.contourf(X,Y, Z, 20)
```

Comment: Give the actual traceback to narrow the search please.

Comment: The `interp2d` [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) states: "This class returns a function whose call method uses spline interpolation to find the value of new points." So you are passing this function in where `contourf` expects a single floating point value.

Comment: @kindall when I comment out the contourf part, the error disappears, but no temp_cubic is created.  So something's still wrong.

edit:  I appear to be stupid.  I was expecting an array to pop out for some reason, not a function.  Let me change things and see what happens, thanks.

Comment: I didn't say the problem is doing the `contourf` call itself. The problem is that the `contourf` call expects a number for its third argument and you're giving it a function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  Specifically, post an example that reproduces the problem, and give your full error message.  This will include a trace-back.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following line.  interp2d returns an interpolation function.  However, you used it in place of the **Z** argument to **countourf**, which is supposed to be a float matrix.  See the [contourf doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf) for details.

In particular:

```
contour(X,Y,Z,N)
make a contour plot of an array Z.
X, Y specify the (x, y) coordinates of the surface
X and Y must both be 2-D with the same shape as Z,
  or they must both be 1-D such that
  len(X) is the number of columns in Z and
  len(Y) is the number of rows in Z.
contour up to N automatically-chosen levels.
```

In short, I believe that you want to apply the function to X and Y to generate the array you pass in as the third argument.

Credit to both the matplotlib documentation and **kindall** for showing the conceptual error of my other possibilities.

Comment: You're definitely right; however, I changed that and I'm still getting an error.

Comment: Edited my post if you're interested in looking